# Passing in IObservable<T> in method

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to pass in a Observable item to a repository layer.

I have the interface

```
public interface Repository{
    IObservable<INotification<bool>> Save(IObservable<T> objects);
}
```

I'm having trouble testing this, and haven't found any examples of people doing something like this.

Is this bad design Rx wise?. I would like to save a stream of results and let the repository buffer them based on its own semantics. Eg the implementation of the repository is in control of Buffer().

Part of the motivation of this is to allow the save method to buffer/flush the last item when the objects stream is closed. It may do this more often, but from the higher level I don't care.

EDIT:

I feel really dumb about the testing, apparently I was mocking the specific call to a specific instance of an observable, which if I used replay, or even do, is actually a new instance of an object causing my mock to return null.

I'm still curious about this pattern though.

Comment: "I'm having trouble testing this" - having trouble because / what is the trouble?

Comment: In theory, it works. In practice, it might be pretty useless since `IObservable` is hardly serializable with common .NET application integration tools ( WCF, OData, etc. ), unless you plan to use this interface within one application

Comment: Yes this kind of defeats the purpose of serialization (I want it now my application is closing!) since the `Observerable`controls the pace of completion.

Comment: The issue is if I call, "do" on the observable before hand, it causes Rx to throw a null exception "source is null". The actual call save is mocked, and seems to be related to do possibly pulling the values out earlier, though I can't seem to use replay/publish/connect to get around this.

@paulpdaniels. What do you recommend?. I wanted to use Observable because it gives a nice signal that everything is done, that way I don't need to give the interface a "Save" method. So I can change the buffering in the implementation of save, and how it persists the streams of data flowing in.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is worth considering the possible semantics of your interface.

```
public interface Repository
{
    IObservable<INotification<bool>> Save<T>(IObservable<T> objects);
}
```

The observable `objects` may be hot or cold, and it may contain delays between successive values, and it may be infinite. You may not envisage your consumers calling it with "unfavourable" observables, but they might.

Also, the result is an observable. So, what should the following code mean?

```
var results = repository.Save(myObservableObjects);
```

This might trigger a save or it might do nothing!

You may have to do the following to actually trigger the save:

```
 results.Subscribe(...);
```

And then what would be the result if two or more observers subscribe to the result observable? Would it just return the existing results? Would it trigger a new save from the objects in the source observable?

The semantics of this kind of repository are just too diverse.

In my opinion, this is the interface that you need:

```
public interface Repository
{
    Task<INotification<bool>> Save<T>(T item);
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
IObservable<INotification<bool>> results =
    from item in items
    from result in Observable.FromAsync(() => repository.Save(item))
    select result;
```

That effectively gives you the full signature that you originally wanted, but you are fully in control of the execution of the query so you know what is saved and when.